# Using utility method for setItemCaptionPropertyId of vaadin dropdown component

Tags: vaadin

I'm using combo box and I've set container data source which is of `AttributeDisplayType` class type.

```
typeBeanItemContainer = new MyBeanItemContainer<AttributeDisplayType>(AttributeDisplayType.class);
typeComboBox.setContainerDataSource(typeBeanItemContainer);
beanFieldGroup.bind(typeComboBox, propertyName(beanFieldGroup.proxy().getClientAttribute().getAttributeDisplayType()));
```

But I want to localize values displayed in combo box. I don't want to create wrapper around `AttributeDisplayType` and use it to as a container data source.

Is there way by which I can use `setItemCaptionPropertyId` and use some utility method to do localization of values displayed in combo box, something like below

```
typeComboBox.setItemCaptionPropertyId(getLocalizedText(propertyName(Lambda.on(AttributeDisplayType.class).getDisplayTypeName().toLowerCase())));
```

or

```
typeComboBox.setItemCaptionPropertyId(getLocalizedText(propertyName(Lambda.on(AttributeDisplayType.class).getDisplayTypeName().toLowerCase())));

public String getLocalizedText(String displayTypeName) {
        return resouceBundle.getKey(displayTypeName);
}
```

I can't add my field or method in existing `AttributeDisplayType` as resource bundle is not available for that class.

Is it possible or do I've to create wrapper and use it's `method/field` as `setItemCaptionPropertyId`?

Comment: You could create an IndexedContainer with a description property that you could load up with your localized description.

Answer (score 2):

```
typeComboBox.setItemCaptionGenerator(new ItemCaptionGenerator() {
            @Override
            public String getItemCaption(AbstractSelect source, Object itemId) {
                AttributeDisplayType type = (AttributeDisplayType) itemId;
                return getText(type.getDisplayTypeName().toLowerCase());
            }
});
```

getText is method which does localization, solutions was so simple and not sure why I was thinking in difficult ways. Thanks to my colleague.

Comment: Could you elaborate more please, because I can't seem to find an `ItemCaptionGenerator` class with a `getText()` method. Also think about marking your response as answer if this is the solution.

Comment: I was marking that as answer but it gave me messages as "You can accept your own answer in 24 hours".

Comment: You are right, that was custom code provided in our code base's framework level.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution would be to use a [GeneratedPropertyContainer](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/datamodel.container.html#datamodel.container.gpc).

You could even think about creating a general localized container. Maybe similar to this (not a full implementation, but it gives you the idea):

```
  public class LocalizedContainer extends GeneratedPropertyContainer {

    public LocalizedContainer(Indexed container) {
      super(container);

      Collection<?> containerPropertyIds = container.getContainerPropertyIds();
      for (final Object containerPropertyId : containerPropertyIds) {
        if (containerPropertyId instanceof String) {
          String localizedPropertyId = containerPropertyId + ".localized";
          addGeneratedProperty(localizedPropertyId, new PropertyValueGenerator<String>() {

            @Override
            public String getValue(Item item, Object itemId, Object propertyId) {
              Object value = item.getItemProperty(containerPropertyId).getValue();
              return getLocalizedValue(value);
            }

            @Override
            public Class<String> getType() {
              return String.class;
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }

    private String getLocalizedValue(Object value) {

      // Do localization here

      return String.valueOf(value);
    }
  }
```

And then you could use `setItemCaptionPropertyId("yourpropertyid.localized")` on the `ComboBox` and wrap your container inside the `LocalizedContainer`.

Comment: Hi, Can you check my question about Vaadin at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783130/vaadin-widget-set-is-not-getting-loaded    . Thanks a lot. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add [Viritin add-on](https://vaadin.com/addon/viritin) to your project. It's TypedSelect component (which allows to use ComboBox as the underlaying implementation), contains similar API as in the example by Archana Mundane, but called just CaptionGenerator and better typed. Usage example with it:

```
    // Better typed alternative for Vaadin select
    final TypedSelect<Person> typedSelect = new TypedSelect<Person>();
    // Uses "NativeSelect" as impl. by default, but all core select types are 
    // supported. E.g.: withSelectType(ListSelect.class);

    // Typed API for setOptions makes its usage easier to figure out where are we 
    // selecting from. Note that its "fluent" so you can chain it directly into
    // constrcutor as well.
    typedSelect.setOptions(options);

    // for most objects you want to customize the caption text. Again, you
    // can use chaind invocation and you'll use lambdas in you java 8 project.
    typedSelect.setCaptionGenerator(new CaptionGenerator<Person>() {

        @Override
        public String getCaption(Person option) {
            return option.getFirstName() + " " + option.getLastName();
        }
    });
```